# Seeking some insight understanding how a simpleCursorAdapter works

Tags: java, android, xml, database, sqlite

Hey guys I was just hoping someone could shed some light on how this code is working and more specifically the simpleCursorAdapter.  The full program is an app that is a to-do list, it's a very simple tutorial the user can input data or "notes" and save to a sqlite data base using cursors and loaders.

So my problem is that there is a specific method that I'm having trouble grasping how it works and as a result I cannot manipulate the way the data is displayed.  I think the problem lies in the fact that I just don't understand how the adapter is taking in a different layout than what is displayed and showing it all in a list view.

```
  private void fillData() {

    // Fields from the database (projection)
    // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
    String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };


    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label }; //I don't quite understand but I know it's just a value for the adapter

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, from,  
        to, 0); /*This line specifically I don't understand how it is working. 
            R.layout.todo_row is a near blank xml, used when there are no "todos"
            with no listviews.  R.layout.todo_list has the listview's but when 
            assigned in the adapter it doesn't work.


    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }
```

Overall I'm trying to make 3 listviews side by side to read data from the DB and just play around.  If anyone could help me out it would be very much so appreciated, thank you.

R.layout.todo_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/reminder" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@+id/TextView01"
        android:textSize="24dp" 
        >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and R.layout.todo_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
           android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" >

        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMiddle"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/list" >
        </ListView>

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listRight"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listMiddle" >
        </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_todos" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The entire class is below

```
package de.vogella.android.todos;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider;
import de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoTable;

/*
 * TodosOverviewActivity displays the existing todo items
 * in a list
 * 
 * You can create new ones via the ActionBar entry "Insert"
 * You can delete existing ones via a long press on the item
 */

public class TodosOverviewActivity extends ListActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
  private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;
  private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
  // private Cursor cursor;
  private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
  private SimpleCursorAdapter middleAdapter;
  private SimpleCursorAdapter rightAdapter;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.todo_list);
    this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
  }

  // Create the menu based on the XML defintion
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.listmenu, menu);
    return true;
  }

  // Reaction to the menu selection
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.insert:
      createTodo();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
          .getMenuInfo();
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/"
          + info.id);
      getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
      fillData();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }

  private void createTodo() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }

  // Opens the second activity if an entry is clicked
  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetailActivity.class);
    Uri todoUri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
    i.putExtra(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);

    startActivity(i);
  }



  private void fillData() {

    // Fields from the database (projection)
    // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
    String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
    String[] middleId = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID };

    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };
    int[] two = new int[] { R.id.label };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, from,
        to, 0);

    middleAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, middleId,
            two, 0);


    setListAdapter(adapter);
   // setListAdapter(middleAdapter);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
      ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
  }

  // Creates a new loader after the initLoader () call
  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID, TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
        MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // data is not available anymore, delete reference
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is a "near blank xml"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my problem is that there is a specific method that I'm having trouble grasping how it works and as a result I cannot manipulate the way the data is displayed.

The method:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, from, to, 0);
```

Well, let's break this constructor down by each parameter:

1. `this`, a Context. The Adapter needs a Context to inflate each row's layout.
2. `R.layout.todo_row`, the row's layout.  Every record in your Cursor will be displayed in this layout.  (Exactly *how* the Cursor is displayed depends on `from` and `to`.)
3. `null`, a Cursor.  This holds all of the data that will be shown in your ListView.
4. `from`, an array of the essential Views in the rows layout.
5. `to`, an array of the essential columns from your Cursor.
6. `0`, flags for when and why the data should be refreshed.

The trick behind every thing is this: the ids in the fourth (`from`) must each match a View in the second parameter (`R.layout.todo_row`). The Strings in fifth parameter must each match a column name in your Cursor. The fourth (`from`) and fifth parameters (`to`) must match one-to-one, because each column is displayed in one View.  That's it really.

---

As you may have realized by now, this note:

> R.layout.todo_row is a near blank xml, used when there are no "todos" with no listviews.

is wrong, sorry.  If you want to display a note when the Cursor is empty add:

```
 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="No data"/>
```

to `todo_list.xml` as described in [`ListActivity`'s documenation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html). By using this "magic id" in your TextView, the note should automatically be shown or hidden when appropriate.

---

All of this only interacts view the first ListView (with the id: `android:id="@android:id/list"), you need to create new Cursors and Adapters to use the other ListViews.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much sir, the problem lied in the to and from.  Now my next question :) what exactly are they doing?  They are pointing to the ID for a textview and somehow putting them into a list view? 
And also when set to R.id.list the program crashes which I find very strange I think I just don't understand what those are really doing, clarification will be very much appreciated haha thank you.

Comment: Perhaps looking at the source code will help: [`SimpleAdapter#getView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#SimpleAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29). `getView()` inflates the row layout and moves into `bindView()`. `bindView()` calls `findViewById()` for each value in `to` and `get()` on each `from`. Next `bindView()` tries to determine what type of data it currently has and what to do with it by looking at the current View: ImageView, TextView, etc. Did this help?

Comment: This is a good example. But how can you set an id to a view with such mechanism? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the source code for SimpleCursorAdapter.  However, it appears that it is mostly doing two things:

1. The query for your data, based on the params you provide in fillData.
2. Looping through the results and populating the list using your template.

In my debuggin, I did notice that it's pretty efficient about filling the list - it only allocates as many rows as are needed to display.  As you scroll, it recycles them rather than free reallocate them.

It looks like your fillData code is good.  You don't say what isn't working so perhaps it's elsewhere.  I've never used onCreateLoader (but probably should), so can't comment on that.

I saw one minor problem: in your R.layout.todo_row, you forgot the orientation attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the code compiles and runs fine and you just want to know what's going on. Well, there are a few things you need to be aware of. The first one is that the `ListView` doesn't take a layout parameter, your activity does in `setContentView`. Your `R.layout.todo_list` is only used by the `TodosOverviewActivity` to create the "screen" or "look" of the activity, that is, 3 `ListView` views side by side. Since the activity is a `ListActivity` it will automatically look for an entry of type `ListView` with an id of `@android:id/list` to automatically hook up the list listeners (just saves you a bit of typing), so your other lists will pretty much just sit there until you hook them up yourself (don't use the same id for items on the same layout). If you need to access these other lists you'll need to use the `findViewById` method in your activity and search for the id of the list you want. For example, we can access the middle list using this:

```
ListView middleList = (ListView)this.findById(R.id.listMiddle);
```

Now that we have the list, we need something to show. The lists are completely empty and you need to bring in data from somewhere. In your case, the data comes from a `Cursor` object you get from a `ContentProvider`. The cursor contains only one column that matters to us, the `TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY` column that has the text we want to display in the list. The problem is that a list doesn't have a clue of what to do with a `Cursor` since the only thing it does is put a view on the screen and scroll it up and down. The `Cursor`, on the other hand, has all the data you want to show but doesn't have a clue of what a `View` is, much less how to put all the data it contains inside one for the list to show. Now you have the `SimpleCursorAdapter` which is, like the name says, an adapter. It is used to make incompatible things work together. On one side you have a list that needs a view, on the other side you have a cursor with the data you want to show, so now you need an adapter that will map each piece of data to part of a view. The `SimpleCursorAdapter` will ask you for 4 things in particular. The first is the layout of the view to show on the list, that is, what should a list item look like. This is the `R.layout.todo_row` that tells the adapter what views should be created. In this case we only have an icon and a `TextView` with the id `R.id.label`. Second, it will ask you for the cursor that contains the data, which is being set inside the `onLoadFinished` method (it is `null` when the adapter is created). Third, it wants to know what columns on the cursor matter. This is the `String[] from` array that says it should look for the data in the `TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY`. Last, it needs to know where in the view to put this data, and this is the `int[] to` that contains the id of the `TextView` you'll be using to display the text, `R.id.label`.

In summary, the adapter is like a map between the data from the cursor and the layout for the view. Now, when the list needs a view to show on screen it will ask the adapter to give it one. The adapter then either recycles or creates a view form the layout you provided, fetches the data for each piece of the layout from the cursor and gives it all ready to go to the list to put it on the screen.